# Continuous function: $ Z=${$x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0$} is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Show that the set $Z=${$x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = 0$} is closed

**My attempt**:

My idea is to show that if $a \in \bar{Z}$ (the set of adherent points), then $f(a) = 0$. Considering only the case that $ \bar{Z} \neq ${} (since $\bar{Z} =${} implies $Z=${}, which is cleary closed), let $a \in \bar{Z}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $ |x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a) | < \varepsilon $. As $a$ is adherent, we can take $x \in Z$ such that $x \in B_{\delta}(a)$. In this case, we will have $|0 - f(a) | < \varepsilon $

Now, I was thinking: Since it is true for really small values of  $ \varepsilon$, does it imply that $f(a) = 0$? I don't know if it is rigorous.

Thanks you very much!

**Edit:** Clearly I do not want to consider that $a \in Z$ previously. Maybe it is better suppose, by contradiction, that $a \not \in Z$ and, then, I can use the existance of $x \in B_{\delta}(a) \cap Z$

Comment: Can somebody explain to me the downvote ?

Comment: Well, we both want to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’ve already proved that a function $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed whenever $F$ is closed, then you can simply observe that $\{0\}$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$, so $Z=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ must be closed as well.

If not, I think that the simplest argument is to show that if $a\in\Bbb R\setminus Z$, then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$: this in turn shows that $a\notin\operatorname{cl}Z$. If $a\in\Bbb R\setminus Z$, then $f(a)\ne 0$. Let $\epsilon=|f(x)|>0$; $f$ is continuous, so there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon=|f(a)|$$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. But if $|f(x)-f(a)|<|f(a)|$, then clearly $f(x)\ne 0$, and we’ve found the desired $\delta$.

An argument closer to what you attempted uses sequences, but it’s available only if you’ve already proved that if $f$ is continuous, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $a$, then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(a)$. If $a\in\operatorname{cl}Z$, then there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $Z$ that converges to $a$. But $f(x_n)=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ converges to $f(a)$, so $f(a)=0$, and therefore $a\in Z$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1** Inverse image of closed set under continuous map is closed

**Hint 2** $x_n\in Z\ni x_n\to x$ then show that $x\in Z$